# OCaml is it possible to creat single if (without else)

Tags: ocaml, control-structure

is it possible to create single if (without else) ?
It is very usable to can use one if

Comment: The  `if-statement` tag is inappropriate for Ocaml. Ocaml has no statements, only *expressions* !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read the [control structures : conditional](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec124) section §6.7.2 of the Ocaml manual.

It is only possible to avoid the `else` when the `then` part (hence the entire `if` expression) is of `unit` type. For example

```
let x = 3 in
   ( if x > 0 then Printf.printf "x is %d\n" x );
   x + 5
;;
```

should print `x is 3`, and return as value 8.

The general rule is that  `if κ then τ` is equivalent to  `if κ then τ else ()` hence  the "then part" `τ` has to be of `unit` type and the "else part" is defaulted to `()` so the entire `if` is of `unit` type.

```
let x = 3 in ( if x > 0 then "abc" ); x + 7 (*faulty example*)
```

won't even compile since `"abc"` is not of `unit` type (like `()` is)

You might *sometimes* use the `ignore` function (from [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html)) on the `then` part to force it to be of `unit` type (but that is worthwhile only when it has *significant* [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29); if you replace `"abc"` by `ignore "abc"` then my faulty example would compile, but remains useless).

However, don't forget that **Ocaml has only expressions** (but *no statements* at all). Side-effecting expressions are usually of `unit` type (but you could, but that is usually frowned upon, define a function which computes some non-`unit` result *and* has a useful side-effect).